# Match 3D camera to a portrait still photo

Tags: camera, lighting, photorealism

I just wonder by any chance if we can match a 3D camera to a portrait still photo. I know that for a wide landscape shot, it is easy since we may have many subjects that allow us to match xyz axis. But how about those close-up shots?

This is one of my works. To do this, I have to manually guess around the angle and match the lighting which takes a long time to get it right.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a blender addon related to this called FaceBuilder.

https://keentools.io/download/facebuilder-for-blender

Comment: Just spent couple hours to firgure out. The keentools only create the camera that match the perspective of the character's face, not the total image. 

wonder if you know how to use it to match with the whole image's perspective?

Comment: Wonder if you can tell me more specific how you do it? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean with total image exactly? What would you expect your result to be? Maybe I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Please have a look below to see some images as an example:

With this image where the character facing camera and her pose is pretty simple. I guess we can get the 3D camera pretty close to real-life camera.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16zHSmUrlDusgEK5AgCD_PFc4X4ev_Rne/view?usp=sharing

But with this image the model pose is more complicated, the camera will be hard to match. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MEnQAjaVX9_hjqfOC8vsxup3T3Awvdm-/view?usp=sharing

Maybe I don't know do it prob. Lemme know what you think. Cheers

Comment: I still haven't quite understood what you are trying to achieve. Are you just trying to figure out the camera specs or are you trying to reconstruct the whole scene to add elements? Are you trying to reconstruct the body pose using a character?

Comment: Yes, what I am trying to do is to reconstruct the whole scene and add 3D elements to the scene. By that, I need to get the camera perspective right.
Sorry for being unclear. Should have let you know about that earlier.